# Law of large numbers applied to $\overline{X}$

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, law-of-large-numbers

The law of large numbers states that if we have $X_1,\ldots X_n$ independent variables which are identically distributed, then:
$$\overline{X}:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i \longrightarrow \mu \quad \mbox{where} \quad \mu = \mathbb{E}(\overline{X})$$
$\overline{X}$ is a random variable whilst $\mu$ is a number; how can it be possible that a random variable converges to a number?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By independence and standard rules for variances,
$$
Var(\bar{X})=\frac{1}{n^2}Var\left(\sum_iX_i\right)=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_iVar(X_i)
$$
Given identical distributions,
$$
\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_iVar(X_i)=\frac{n}{n^2}Var(X_1)\to0
$$
Hence, the variability in the sample mean disappears, so to speak, when computing it over many realizations of the underlying random variable. Given that the mean is also unbiased for the expected value, convergence in probability follows.

As an example, if you toss dice infinitely often, luck will "average out", with you tossing 3.5 on average.